# CRM: plugin error - onCreate (<Message>Expected non-empty Guid.</Message>)

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

i have an issue: the error...` when creating a new record

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: Expected non-empty Guid.Detail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
  <ErrorCode>-2147220989</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
  <Message>Expected non-empty Guid.</Message>
  <Timestamp>2013-01-31T09:23:30.4406111Z</Timestamp>
  <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
  <TraceText>
```

The Code...`  sets the fields to values. i have also tried

```
Pline.Id = new Guid();

Pline.Id = a; //(a is a guid ref to parent record)


Entity Pline = new Entity("bc_packlines");
if (b.Attributes.ContainsKey("mins_sum"))
{
    BlockMins = ((Decimal)((AliasedValue)b["mins_sum"]).Value);
}

Pline.Attributes["bc_packlinesid"] = Pline.Id;
Pline.Attributes["bc_pack"] = a;
Pline.Attributes["bc_type"] = "948110004";
Pline.Attributes["bc_minutespurchased"] = BlockMins;
Pline.Id = a;
service.Create(Pline);
```

Any ideas please? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of that is a bit confusing, especially

```
Pline.Attributes["bc_packlinesid"] = Pline.Id;
// ...
Pline.Id = a;
```

You should not need to set the Id of your new entity explicitly so remove:

```
Pline.Id = a;
```

Edit: Also you say that `a` is the Guid to a parent record - so how/why would you set as the PK of another record? That won't work fullstop.

Secondly, in this line

```
Pline.Attributes["bc_packlinesid"] = Pline.Id;
```

You are setting the value of the field `bc_packlinesid` to an empty guid, as the Id of the record you are creating is not yet set. This means you are trying to get the entity to refer to itself? It doesn't sound right to me but if it is, you will need to do this as a second step, after

```
var newId = service.Create(PLine)
```

Something like

```
Pline.Attributes["bc_packlinesid"] = newId;
service.Update(PLine);
```

That is if that is even possible, I'm not sure if CRM will allow an entity to parent-child itself.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this, 1st edit fetch statement

```
<attribute name='productid' groupby='true' alias='productid' />
```

Which is what each new bc_packlines is based on anyway:
then ...

```
productid = ((Guid)((AliasedValue)b["productid"]).Value);

                        BlockMins = ((Decimal)((AliasedValue)b["mins_sum"]).Value);

                        Entity Pline = new Entity("bc_packlines");
                        Pline.Id = productid;
```

Thanks :) hope this helps someone

Comment: You are setting the Id of your new entity to the Id of another entity. This will work, but makes absolutely no sense. I look forward to your next question when this logic bites you in the behind.

Comment: Listen to @glosrob - what you're doing is syntactically correct but (most likely) wrong and not what you intend to achieve. The *id* will be assigned to the entity by CRM. Let it do just that. You both will end up much more happy that way.

Comment: Yeah thanks :) i noticed the issue aswell actually and will update the solution soon. this issue i have been having having is i need to create new records based on the return of a fetch... which have values coming from 3 different associated levels of different records. But yeah your both right this way is wrong as a product can be in many opportunity products & therefore i get duplicates often & cant use the guid. thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 0):

you should not set the PK of your record, the CRM will create it so you need to remove this

line

```
 Pline.Id = a;
```

and to create a relationship to the parent entity you have its id and you write the following

code

```
Pline.Attributes["bc_packlinesid"]=new CrmEntityRefrence(Pline.EntityLogicalName,parentEntityID);
```